# How to convert calendar year to financial year

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date, datetime

Trying to convert calendar year to financial. I have a dataframe as below. Each ID will have multiple records. And the records might have missing months like 3rd row 3 month is missing

```
 df:

ID  Callender Date 
1   01-01-2022
1   01-02-2022 
1   01-04-2022 
1   01-05-2022
1   01-05-2022
2   01-01-2022
2   01-07-2023
```

Expected output:

As the financial year starts form July to June
eg: FY 2022 means:

i.e.

```
July -2021  - This is 1st month in the financial year, 
August- 2021 - This is 2nd month in the financial year
Sep -2021 - This is 3rd month in the financial year
Oct -2021 - This is 4th month in the financial year
Nov 2021 - - This is 5th month in the financial year
Dec 2021- - This is 6th month in the financial year
jan 2022- This is 7th month in the financial year
feb 2022- This is 8th month in the financial year
March 2022- This is 9th month in the financial year
April 2022- This is 10th month in the financial year
May 2022- This is 11th month in the financial year
June 2022- This is 12th month in the financial year`
```

Expected output: Convert Callender year to financial year:

```
 ID  Callender_Date    Financial_Year    Fiscal_Month
    1   01-01-2022         2022             7
    1   01-02-2022         2022             8
    1   01-04-2022         2022             10
    1   01-05-2022         2022             11
    1   01-06-2022         2022             12
    2   01-01-2021         2021             7
    2   01-07-2021         2022             1`
```

Tried with below code- found in some other question

```
df['Callender_Date '] = df['Callender_Date '].asfreq('J-July') - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
# convert the column to datetime (if not already):
df['Callender_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Callender_Date'], dayfirst=True)

df['Financial_Year'] =df['Callender_Date'].dt.to_period('Q-JUL').dt.qyear
df['Fiscal_Month'] = (df['Callender_Date'] + pd.DateOffset(months=6)).dt.month
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   ID Callender_Date  Financial_Year  Fiscal_Month
0   1     2022-01-01            2022             7
1   1     2022-02-01            2022             8
2   1     2022-04-01            2022            10
3   1     2022-05-01            2022            11
4   1     2022-06-01            2022            12
5   2     2021-01-01            2021             7
6   2     2021-07-01            2021             1
```

Comment: thankyou. By correcting a minor  Q-JUN , i get correct financial year now. Thank u. Also  how to  get the vice versa? like from financial year to the calender year ? The question asked here  is different but since same example so just wanted to know hence asked.